# MUI_ICON is being ignored

Tags: nsis

I have an NSIS installation script I wrote, and now I'm trying to customize the installer icon. By default, the generated install file looks like this:

[image]

I want to customize it to use a different icon however. Here's the code I added:

```
!include MUI.nsh

!define MUI_ICON my_icon.ico
```

I've got the `my_icon.ico` file in the same directory as this `.nsi` script, and yes it is a valid ICO file. Yet, when I compile the script, effectively nothing happens – the icon does not change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the correct icon on the taskbar and in alt+tab when your installer is running?

This is probably just Explorer caching the icon. I can reproduce it on my system as well:

[image: Explorer file list and file properties]

If makensis cannot find the icon it should complain and your code looks correct:

```
!include MUI.nsh

!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\arrow-install.ico"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
SectionEnd
```

Open a new instance of Notepad or any other application that uses a standard open dialog and navigate to the folder where your .exe is and you should see the correct icon when setting the filter to "All files". You could also open the .exe in a icon or resource editor to verify that it has the correct icon...

Comment: This led me to the correct answer. What did the trick was adding this line: `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES`

Comment: MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES should not matter but if some time passes the icon cache entry might no longer be valid and trigger a read from the now updated .exe file...

Comment: When I include that line, it compiles the executable with the icon. When I subsequently exclude that line, the executable reverts to the old icon.

Comment: Again, that line should not matter. Just look at the icon in the titlebar when the application is running, it should be correct with or without a instfiles page. Don't trust the file listing in Explorer, use another tool (angusj.com/resourcehacker) if you really believe it is not a cache issue...

Comment: The icons in the titlebar, or the taskbar, or Alt-Tab are all incorrect without that line.

Comment: It works for me. The `Icon` attribute is set by the MUI_INTERFACE macro (`Icon "${MUI_ICON}"`) which is called by the MUI_PAGE_INIT macro which in turn is called by all pages (MUI_INTERFACE only performs its actions once though). If you add `!define MUI_VERBOSE 4` to the top of your .nsi you should be able to see the icon command. In my case I see: `Icon: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\arrow-install.ico"`

Comment: I had exactly the same problem; Adding `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES` makes the icon work, and removing it reverts to the default NSIS icon (NSIS 3). It seems to work as long as you have `MUI_PAGE_*` and/or `MUI_LANGUAGE`set. If you don't have either, then icon stops working.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike: If you don't use MUI_PAGE* then there is no reason to use MUI at all and then you can just use the normal Icon attribute...

Comment: @Anders at the point where I went to set the icon, I had nothing but custom views that I made with the NSIS Dialog Designer, so the icon didn't work. I later set the MUI language and used some of their pages, but not before fighting to figure out why the icon wouldn't change on the .exe